# Reference Range return specific value

Tags: worksheet-function

I need to refer the number of needed hours to the table in the picture and reference back to total needed, so they have -190 Needed Hours, so they would need 4 people. Is there a worksheet function I can use for this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwQLc.png]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a formula without seeing which rows and columns your data is in. Adjust the following accordingly:

```
=INDEX(E2:E6,MATCH(A2,C2:C6,-1))
```

- C2:C6 is the range with the numbers 0, -1, -33, -66, -99
- A2 is the cell with the Needed Hours
- E2:E6 is the range with the hours to be returned

You do realise that your number does not fall into any of the ranges in your sample table. This formula will return a `4` for any lookup value greater than 99. You can add more rows to your lookup table, of course and adjust the formula to include these rows.